# ASP.Net Identity - AddLogin userId becomes null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity

I use ASP.Net Identity and it works as expected, except when associating an external login provider.

For example, when I call `Repository.UserManager.AddLogin()` (or Async) I get the exception:

> The UserId field is required.

While debugging I made sure that I was passing the correct `userId` to the function, I even hardcoded it.

For `loginInfo` I tried with both Facebook and Google providers.

[image]

In the watch window we can see that I correctly specified the user ID to the method, and in the Watch window `User.Id` has the correct value, while `userId` is `null`.

Unfortunately the source code is not yet public on Codeplex so I cannot look at the implementation.

Comment: What was your code before you were hard coding that value in?

Comment: Before hardcoding `userId` the value was `User.Identity.GetUserId()`. I moved the method to my business layer, this method is called from the `Controller`

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have run into the same problem.

Comment: @jt234 Unfortunately no

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this issue by reinstalling(updating) references to EntityFramework and Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.

This will, however, create an incompatibility with existing CodeFirst migrations and database.

Since my service is not yet live, it was not a problem for me to just delete the database and recreate the migrations, however it might be a deal breaker for a service already running.

What I also did, was changed a line in IdentityModels.cs in function onModelCreating from:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey<string>(l => l.UserId);
```

to:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().HasKey(l => new { l.UserId, l.LoginProvider, l.ProviderKey });
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you forget to assign the UserId property to user.Id in user.Logins

```
        user.Logins.Add(new IdentityUserLogin
        {
            LoginProvider = externalLogin.LoginProvider,
            ProviderKey = externalLogin.ProviderKey,
            UserId=user.Id
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

You should first save the user as an ApplicationUser:

```
var user = new ApplicationUser() { Id = User.Identity.GetUserId(), UserName = "user", Email = "user@domain.com" };
IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user);
```

Then you can create a login record:

```
result = await UserManager.AddLoginAsync(user.Id, new UserLoginInfo("loginProvider", "providerKey"));
```